# What sensor to use for creating a parallax effect on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, move, sensors, parallax

I have a scene divided in 3 different planes and I want to move these planes, left or right relative to the rotation of the device on the axis, so when the device is at 0 degree to the surface the planes will be on center. I see this effect on the home screen of a game from my iPod touch (first generation).
Which sensor I must work with for creating a similar effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve a parallax effect, add the CoreMotion framework to your project and construct a `CMMotionManager`.  Then for a device that has a gyroscope, you can use `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` and inspect `motion.attitude.roll` in your handler block.

For a device that doesn't have a gyroscope, you can use `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` and inspect `accelerometerData.acceleration.x`, or you can use `UIAccelerometer` and implement `UIAccelerometerDelegate`.  Either way, you'll probably want to create a low-pass filter to help distinguish gravity from linear acceleration.  The GLGravity project has an example of this.

See the section on [Motion Events](http://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW1) in the Event Handling Guide for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out for me. The accelerometer is a good solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this UIView category
https://github.com/Przytua/UIView-MWParallax

you get the parallax effect on chosen UIView (or it's subclasses) objects with simply setting 1 property value